# How to do an ElasticSearch Select Distinct

Tags: elasticsearch

I just want to do the following request with elasticsearch.

In SQL :

```
Select distinct(id) from my_table where userid = '20' or activity = '9';
```

I just have :

```
{
   "query" : {
        "bool" : {
               "should" : [ 
                  { "term" : { "userid" : "20" } }, 
                  { "term" : { "activity" : "9" } }
               ]
         }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You're almost there, you simply need to add a [`terms` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) to your query

```
{
   "query" : {
        "bool" : {
               "should" : [ 
                  { "term" : { "userid" : "20" } }, 
                  { "term" : { "activity" : "9" } }
               ]
         }
    },
    "aggs":{
        "unique_ids": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "id"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect :)

Comment: @Val by doing so i run into "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [some_id] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory." Any ideas how to avoid it by modifying queue.? Also mabye it ist possible to define a rool haw not unique elements are thrown and maybe even take some fields of one and some form another?

Comment: @aholbreich there is nothing you can do on the query level to avoid it. You can either enable fielddata on the fields in question or change your mapping from text to e.g keyword.

Answer (score 7):

As answer above just works perfectly, If you want to do only `DISTNICT` on a certain field without any search or so then simply just do use `aggs`

**This SQL**

```
SELECT DISTINCT FULL_NAME from users;
```

**EQUIVALENT TO**

```
POST users/_search
{
"aggs":{
        "unique_names": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "FULL_NAME.keyword"
            }
        }
    },
     "_source": false
  
}
```

I know this answer does not directly match the question though I believe it will help people who's new on ES stack.

Comment: at least up to ES 8.5.2 "SELECT DISTINCT" is not yet supported and therefore the above answer does not work. 
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "verification_exception",
        "reason": """Found 1 problem
line 1:8: SELECT DISTINCT is not yet supported"""
      }
    ],
    "type": "verification_exception",
    "reason": """Found 1 problem
line 1:8: SELECT DISTINCT is not yet supported"""
  },
  "status": 400
}

Answer (score 2):

Text fields are not optimized for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true

Kindly use the below snippet.

"field": "id.keyword"