# Elasticsearch - Search by a field but distinct another field

Tags: elasticsearch

What I mean would be equivalent of this SQL query:

```
SELECT distinct fieldA
from DB
where fieldB like '%value%'
```

What is the Term Aggregation of this query in elastic search?

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40381339/how-to-do-an-elasticsearch-select-distinct/40381455#40381455

Answer (score 0):

You can use [wildcard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) query in conjunction with [terms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) aggregation to fetch distinct values for the field.

You can use the following query to get the results.

```
POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "fieldB": {
        "value": "*ali*"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "distinct_fieldA": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "fieldA",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this works

Comment: tnx for your help! but this is also returning all rows! even I changed size to 0 still the same