# How to get aggregate result in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I need to get distinct values matching some condition in ElasticSearch where the data in this format. The SQL version will be.

`select distinct kind_id from xxx where timestamp < date_add(now(), interval -1 day)`

The data in elasticsearch is

```
{
    "id": "19504ec6bacd46aca302dc7e848aa8a1",
    "@kind": "some_data",
    "@kind_id": 4,
    "timestamp": "2022-09-06T00:02:36.697Z",
    "data": "some data"
}
```

Comment: [I hope this link about select in elastic search helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40381339/how-to-do-an-elasticsearch-%20select-distinct)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) on your `kind_id` field to get the required results.

```
{
    "size":0,
    "query": {
        "range": {
            "timestamp": {
                "gte": "now-1d/d",
                "lt": "now"
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "distinct_kind": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "@kind_id"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice Amit, you should also add the query part with the range query on timestamp ;-)

Comment: Thank Amit, please write the query part too, because I'm far from ES and will suffer on it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @jiromm i did and updated answer

Comment: Thanks one more time Amit, but after execution I'm getting several results with the same @kind_id (which is 4 in my case). I was expecting to see different, not repeating results. It seems like the response does not match to request.

Comment: @jiromm, you need to look at the aggs part of result, one sec in will update that part for you.

Comment: @jiromm can you try the latest query